# onClick works fine with USB debugging but not in released .apk

Tags: android

I want my app to be started when the user clicks on the widget. My code works fine while working with my phone connected via USB. After exporting the .apk and reinstalling the app the onclick part is no more working.

```
    for (int appWidgetID : appWidgetIds) {            
        Intent intent = new Intent("android.intent.action.MAIN");
        intent.addCategory("android.intent.category.LAUNCHER");

        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
        intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("de.cwalz.android.woltlabVendor","de.cwalz.android.woltlabVendor.MainActivity"));
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, 0);
        RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget);
        remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.layoutContainer, pendingIntent);

        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetID, remoteViews);
    }
```

Comment: `the onclick part is no more working.` ?????

Comment: well, the whole code is not working. My app is not starting when I click on the widget.

Comment: Check your proguard config. When obfuscating classes sometimes code can get screwed up.

Comment: Like for example keeping class names ( de.cwalz.android.woltlabVendor )

Comment: Collect the **logcat** from a run attempt of the release app.  In the rare cases (wakelocks, etc) where having the USB cable connected can alter behavior, get the app to fail without the USB, then *immediately* connect the cable and pull the log, which will stretch seconds to hours (depending on message rate) back in time.